# Workbook_Open throws an error that manual run does not

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

When running automatically via Workbook_Open, it throws a 91 error.  However, running the same code manually does not.  It's machine specific.  No problems on a different PC.  Also, error 91 does not get caught in the error trap.  I've checked all my Trust Center setting between the two PCs.  Identical.  What could this be?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

On Err GoTo ErrHandler

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Debug.Print "point 1. Err# = " & Err.Number
    Workbooks.Open "any file and path here"
    Debug.Print "Point 2. Err# = " & Err.Number
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Debug.Print "point 3. Err# = " & Err.Number
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "point 4. Err# = " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

> Output when run automatically upon Workbook_Open:

point 1. Err# = 0

point 2. Err# = 91

point 3. Err# = 91

point 4. Err# = 91

Notice that at point 3 the code avoids the error trap even though there is a 91 error.

Output when the code is triggered manually:

point 1. Err# = 0

point 2. Err# = 0

point 3. Err# = 0

point 4. Err# = 0

Comment: Looks like you did not include a full path.

Comment: The file name is irrelevant.  It's a dummy name.  If anyone else uses the code, they'd need to add the path/file to appropriate file.  Running either manually or automatically upon open, the file opens perfectly.  The problem is that an error 91 is throw when running using the automatic run "workbook_open".

Comment: You Open a new Workbook while the open event is running. ..... weird. Perhaps your machine is too slow ??!! After open the new workbook, which one is the active one ?

Comment: The newly opened file is the active workbook, if that's what you are asking.  Works fine from the Workbook_Open on the one machine.  I've been using this for years without a problem.  The machine that runs correctly is the slower of the two.  I've checked everything in Excel options side-by-side - setting, submenus and other than an Adobe add-in and a few Thesaurus research options, everything is identical.

Answer (score 1):

The machine it was failing on had an Excel Add-Ins "Euro Currency Tools". Add-In selected.  Turn this off and errors go away.  I was able to do the same on the 'good' machine as well.